# I have data in Firestore ,and filed with values , but some of them shows as null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firestore, and I am fetching the data from firestore to my app, and translate the latitude and longitude to address and it's work ok with other documents, but one of the documents it shows me an error that this field is null, but it has a value as you can see

[image]

I always face this problem in Firestore, so sometimes I deleted the document and recreated it again , but I am tired to do that every time, what's is the problem with my Firestore? 
Can anyone help me with this?

This is the method to translate the latitude and longitude

```
 Future<String> gymLocation ;
   @override
  void initState() {

 gymLocation = translate.getAddressFromLatLng(widget.gym.gym_region_lat_long.latitude,widget.gym.gym_region_lat_long.longitude);



Future<String> getAddressFromLatLng(double lat , double long) async {
 String stringAddress='';
 try {
  List<Placemark> p = await geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, 
  long);
 final coordinates = new Coordinates(lat, long);
 var address = await 
Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
var first = address.first;
Placemark place = p[0];
final cor2 = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(place.name);
var ad2 = cor2.first;

stringAddress = first.addressLine;

  print(stringAddress +' current address');
  print('${first.featureName} ,\n${first.addressLine}');
  print('${ad2.coordinates}');
 //  return string_address;
} catch (e) {
print(e);
}
return stringAddress;
 }
```

and this is the method to show the address in Text widget

```
gymAddressContainter(gym_model gym) {
return FutureBuilder<String>(
future: gymLocation,
builder:(context, snapshot)
{
 if (snapshot.hasError) {
 return Center(child: Text('No data'));
 }
 else if (snapshot.hasData) {
   return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        adressText(
            widget.gym.gym_address['g_phone'].toString(), Icons.phone,
            Colors.green),
        adressText(widget.gym.gym_address['g_email'], Icons.email,
            Colors.amber),
        adressText(widget.gym.gym_address['g_website'], Icons.public,
            Colors.blue),
        adressText(snapshot.data, Icons.location_on, Colors.pink)
      ],
     )
    );
  }
  else return Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator());
}

  );
  }
```

and this is how I map the document from firrestore to dart

```
 gym_model.map(dynamic obj){
 this.gym_name = obj['gym_name'];
 this.gym_region = obj['gym_region'];
 this.gphoto= obj['gphoto'];
  this.gym_region_lat_long = obj['gym_region_lat_long'];
  this.gym_city_point = obj['gym_city_point'];

 this.gym_address['g_email']= obj['gym_address']['g_email'];
 this.gym_address['g_phone'] =obj['gym_address']['g_phone'];
 this.gym_address['g_website'] = obj['gym_address']['g_website'];
```

The other documents work fine but only with this gym Rashad sport club, and it has a value ..

Always have a problem in Firestore, when I create a collection with and create documents and put values for each document , some of the documents shows as null, and give me this message error

**PlatformException(failed, Failed, null)**

Comment: A bit of code snippet might help.

Comment: @Sukhi  , I added

Comment: Alright. But I see that you've added it as an answer. Please get accustomed to SO's way of work. You'll have to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can take a look and help (rather than going through the entire code)

Comment: Did you check if snapshot/obj has the right content ?

Comment: gymLocation = translate.getAddressFromLatLng(widget.gym.gym_region_lat_long.latitude,widget.gym.gym_region_lat_long.longitude);

Comment: Future<String> gymLocation ;

Comment: @override
  void initState() {

     gymLocation = translate.getAddressFromLatLng(widget.gym.gym_region_lat_long.latitude,widget.gym.gym_region_lat_long.longitude);

Comment: It works fine with other documents , only sow null with this document **Rashad sport club**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208517/discussion-between-suna-arun-and-sukhi).

Comment: @Sukhi .. I edited the question , and i think the answer is hidden now , thans

Comment: If I understand correctly you after recreate of the document issue is solved for particular item. Than it seems to me that you should add code how do you connect, create and update data in Firestore. Are you using the same method for creation and recreation of document?